# How to run shell commands on file without saving?

Tags: external-command, save

For example, if I want to run `tidy` on a file

```
r! tidy %
```

But I have to save the file beforehand. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:range! command
```

This will run an external command, pipe the lines specified in *range* to it and replace *range* with the output of the command.

As a special case, `%` as a range includes all lines in the buffer. (see `help :%`) So this should do what you want:

```
:%! tidy
```

Answer (score 1):

@dan-j answer, as stated, replace the lines with the output.
To run the file in a shell (without saving) use

```
:w command
```

e.g.:
`:w !tidy` or `:w !bash`

and thanks @james at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758489/running-python-code-in-vim-without-saving) for the answer

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!